# Get the position of window in Kivy

Tags: python-3.x, kivy

I want to know the position of my App window in pixel coordinates. For example if window is at the top left corner, I should get (0, 0). How can I achieve this?

`window.top` and `window.left` are not useful. They just give some very large values. I don't know what they represent.

Comment: On a `linux` platform I have used `subprocess.Popen(['xwininfo', '-root'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)`, then parse the output to get both position and size of the App window.